# Why I have an Error when importing scanpy._compat?

Tags: conda, failed-installation, scanpy

Hi I'm new here so sorry for my language which could result inaccurate.
I'm working with a conda environment in which I installed scanpy. However, when I import the module scanpy._compat, it returns an import error:

`from scanpy._compat import Literal`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scanpy._compat'`

I tried to upgrade scanpy:
`pip install --upgrade scanpy` and I also created another conda environment following installation steps present on scanpy github (https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/blob/master/docs/installation.rst). In each of the last two cases everything works well except for the import of scanpy._compat module.

Someone knows if I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: you could open a python shell in that conda environment and try different versions of your import statement until it works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`_compat.py`](https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/blob/master/scanpy/_compat.py) you will note that the following code is provided:

First:

```py
try:
    from typing import Literal
```

And for the exception:

```py
except ImportError:
    try:
        from typing_extensions import Literal
    except ImportError:

        class LiteralMeta(type):
            def __getitem__(cls, values):
                if not isinstance(values, tuple):
                    values = (values,)
                return type('Literal_', (Literal,), dict(__args__=values))

        class Literal(metaclass=LiteralMeta):
            pass
```

Consequently, when you are trying to `import Literal`, you could just as well circumvent the question by simply `importing typing` and do `typing.Literal` (python version `>3.8` ) for whatever the situation you wanted to apply the code for.

However, the question suggests that `scanpy` cant be imported at all. Ensure that after installing the environment that you also activate it:

`$ conda info --envs` to find out the names of the environments you have available
`$ conda activate [relevant env name]` to activate the relevant conda environment.

To then try the code again:

`$ python` to enter the pythoninterpreter

`> from scanpy._compat import Literal` to test whether the import works.